# Comparing a SAML response with RSA Key to IDP metadata with x509

Tags: encryption, saml

I am trying to debug a SAML configuration. I am setting up a SP and was provided with metadata that includes an X509 certificate. The SAMLResponse that I get from the IDP have an RSAKey. I am assuming that the modulus of both should match (as well as the modulus of the private key which I dont have access to).

Using openssl, I can get the modulus and modulus md5:

```
$ openssl x509 -in idp.crt -modulus -noout
Modulus=CB123123
$ openssl x509 -in idp.crt -modulus -noout | openssl md5
5a562
```

The x509 Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)

The SAMLResponse has a modulus and exponent

```
        <KeyValue>
            <RSAKeyValue>
                <Modulus>
                    wb3JBTztiDtGQ
                </Modulus>
                <Exponent>ABC</Exponent>
            </RSAKeyValue>
        </KeyValue>
```

How can I confirm if the x509 certificate modulus matches the RSA modulus / what format is the SAMLResponse modulus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found a way to do it.

```
$ openssl x509 -in cert.crt -modulus -noout
Modulus=c1b2e3
$ echo wb3JBTztiDtGQ | base64 -d | od -t x1
c1 b2 e3
```